# How to determine if image is something or not?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a trained model that determines if an image contains either cat or dog. I'm using SVM to classify. I want a new model that determines if an image is a mouse or not. It's different from the first model that classifies into 2 classes. This new model will return TRUE or FALSE only.

I don't think I can use a classifier model since I have only 1 class; the mouse. I don't intend to use the first model or anything related to it in the 2nd model.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to be able to predict if an image has a mouse, this is still a classification problem where you're classifying images into two classes -  Mouse and Not a Mouse.

Any classifier you intend to use might need to learn a boundary to separate the mouse images from non mouse images in the n-dimensional input space.

In case you employ a neural network, you could make do with just one output neuron that will ideally give high probability when the image is a mouse and low when there isn't a mouse in the image.

Comment: I'm interested in this neural network, it looks like what I want to do other than training a classifier model. How do I proceed on building this? I don't what to do next. Any links for a start?

Comment: I'm not sure how much you know. But, assuming you have a labeled dataset(images labeled mouse /non-mouse), you can start to build a Convolutional neural network. This type of neural network works best with images. To gain theoretical knowledge, this course helped me a lot - https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks?specialization=deep-learning#syllabus  . But there are several blogs with articles on image classification. Also, make a decision on whether you'd like to use pytorch or tensorflow or keras frameworks to build your CNN. Pytorch and keras are easier to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach, the one that seems to have better results in research and industry is to use a Neural Network, a CNN (convolutional network to be more precise, although a linear forward layer would also work). 
 
Nothing has changed from cats vs dogs to mouse vs not mouse. Still a classification problem.Since you are using an SVM I assume you don't have a lot of data, maybe try using transfer learning with resnet models ? It might yield good results.

If it's still not enough, you can still use SVM for classification 1-mouse 0- not a mouse.!

Hope it helped !

Best!

Comment: in order to train the model, I need to prepare images of mice and teach the model that these are mice. but I can't just prepare 2nd set of images that are not mice right? Like I could put images of anything like horse, house, shoes, etc. Right?

Comment: Can you scrape google images for other animals? and then label them as 0 - non rat ?

Comment: Does it mean I can use a photo of shoe or pen? and label it as not a mouse? I know what u mean but shouldn't have a better than this? what I have is mind is that my dataset only contains images of mice and train the model. After that, the model will just give me a probability (in %) that the input image is a mouse instead of classifying  it as a mouse or not mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a mouse class, you can use supervised learning. 
when you train your model, let the model learn what is a mouse by defining him that this is a specific object is mouse and define him what is not a mouse...

With this approach you just need a class of mouse to define your model and "teach" him what is a mouse, after this, your model will classify "mouse" and "not mouse"

Answer (score 0):

There are two option to approach the problem:

1.) You consider the problem as a two-class classification task. Then you train a classifier with samples from the class (images showing a mouse), and samples where the images do not depict a mouse. This approach works in general. To this end, you can still train an SVM, or you train a neural network. If you have only few samples, using SVM or tranfer learning with neural networks works good in most cases. Note that for applying a SVM, you have to define discriminative features (like HOG).

A question that arises with this approach is which images to select for the not-mouse class.

2.) You consider the problem as a one-class classification task. In this case, you only need samples of your desired class and the machine learning model is trained to recognize deviations from the class.

There a classical approaches like one-class SVM, where you train only on positive samples by fitting a hypersphere around the feature vectors of your class.

If you want to apply neural networks, you could use for example DROCC (https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12718)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two detailed questions inside your origin question

Question1:

```
I don't think I can use a classifier model since I have only 1 class - which is the Mouse
```

Actually you could still use a classifier model for two label, label=0 means this image (this instance) is "not a mouse",  label=1 means this image (this instance) is "a mouse".

After training in instances with label=0 and label=1, your classifier will be able to output probability of whether it's a mouse.

Question2:

```
And I don't intend to use the first model or anything related to it in the 2nd model
```

In general, it's a [transfer learning problem](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-transfer-learning-for-image-classification-f3c7e0ec1a14), so the answer is some pre-train could be helpful for problem without too much instances.

However, detail to your question, which uses a model trained with cat and dog to help prediction of mouse, I think it isn't useful.